How can I dynamically add wrapper to an Angular component?
In my project I have wrapper classes that are reused often and some contain the 'gap' css property. Now I have a component that loads data asynchronously and that component is hidden if the returned data is empty.
The problem I face is that the wrappers I used to surround my component are still displayed and therefore cause the gap to activate. Below is an example with two wrappers, but depending on the use-cases it could be more or other wrappers that are needed.
At the moment:
Working data:
<card-wrapper>
  <specific-margin-wrapper>
    <component-loading-data />
  </specific-margin-wrapper>
</card-wrapper>

Without data:
<card-wrapper>
  <specific-margin-wrapper>
    <component-loading-data style="display: none" />
  </specific-margin-wrapper>
</card-wrapper>

My goal:
Working data:
<card-wrapper>
  <specific-margin-wrapper>
    <component-loading-data />
  </specific-margin-wrapper>
</card-wrapper>

Without data:
<card-wrapper style="display: none" >
  <specific-margin-wrapper style="display: none" >
    <component-loading-data style="display: none" />
  </specific-margin-wrapper>
</card-wrapper>

I want to "display: none" the wrapper classes when the child-component is not displayed too.
I tried to use css pseudo classes like :empty, but that didn't fully work:
:host:empty {
  display: none;
}

Is there a css (less) solution that works like :empty but includes children with display:none ?
Or some ngTemplate / ngContent magic that let's me dynamically add wrapper inside my component.
Ideally I want a solution within my "component-loading-data" so that I don't need to change the parent component where I use it
EDIT:
Added StackBlitz example

Can you create reproducible example on stackblitz?

Added StackBlitz example

Unfortunately, I didn't find a solution inside my loading-component, but I have a somewhat clean solution by referencing a parent element via id in the template.
I've created a directive that allows to hide given elements:
@Directive()
export abstract class HideableContainerDirective {
  private readonly platformId = inject(PLATFORM_ID);
  private readonly document: Document = inject(DOCUMENT);
  private readonly renderer: Renderer2 = inject(Renderer2);

  @Input() public hideableComponentId?: string;

  protected hideComponent(): void {
    if (!isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) return;

    if (this.hideableComponentId) {
      const element = this.document.getElementById(this.hideableComponentId);
      if (element) {
        this.renderer.setStyle(element, 'display', 'none');
      }
    }
  }
}

Components that need to be hidden can extend the Directive and call the hideComponent() function accordingly.
export class MessageContainerComponent extends HideableContainerDirective implements OnInit {

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    const data = this.loadData();
    if (data === undefined) {
      this.hideComponent();
    }
  }
}

And set an id in the template to hide the referenced component:
<card-wrapper id='custom_data_container'>
  <specific-margin-wrapper>
    <component-loading-data [hideableComponentId]="'custom_data_container'" />
  </specific-margin-wrapper>
</card-wrapper>


You can use the @if control flow to remove the component from the template. However, if you prefer a CSS-based solution, you can use the :has selector to set display: none on the parent element based on its child’s state.
specific-margin-wrapper.component.css
:host:has(.no-data){
  display: none;
}

Forked Example

I have multiple wrappers, so I would need to apply this to every wrapper and all of them need to get the no-data class. I think that would cause too many calculations. My wrappers are used very often

You can use template reference variables and @ContentChild or contentChild signal to show/hide the component, we can use @HostBinding('style.display') decorator to dynamically add the style to the host element(the wrapper).
<app-scroll-wrapper>
  <app-card-wrapper>
    <app-specific-margin-wrapper>
      <div class="no-data" #noData></div> <!-- template reference variable -->
    </app-specific-margin-wrapper>
  </app-card-wrapper>
</app-scroll-wrapper>

TS:
@Component({
  ...
})
export class SpecificMarginWrapperComponent {
  // @ContentChild('noData') noData!: ElementRef<any>;
  noData: Signal<ElementRef<any> | undefined> = contentChild('noData');

  @HostBinding('style.display')
  get displayStyle() {
    return !this.noData() ? 'block' : 'none';
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.noData());
  }
}

Full Code:
import {
  Component,
  ContentChild,
  ElementRef,
  HostBinding,
  contentChild,
  Signal,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-specific-margin-wrapper',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './specific-margin-wrapper.component.html',
  styleUrl: './specific-margin-wrapper.component.css',
})
export class SpecificMarginWrapperComponent {
  // @ContentChild('noData') noData!: ElementRef<any>;
  noData: Signal<ElementRef<any> | undefined> = contentChild('noData');

  @HostBinding('style.display')
  get displayStyle() {
    return !this.noData() ? 'block' : 'none';
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.noData());
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

It is possible that my wrappers are used in any order and any amount and I want to hide every wrapper if the deepest child is empty. So I think getting the content child in every wrapper and passing on the noData id would cause too many calculations
